# how to pass value from one controller to another controller in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Logged User Id stored into another table. How to Pass the Login UserId to the another controller.
** public async Task Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
{

```
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

            var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(3),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                username=user.UserName,
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }
   Login **
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use Temp Data :**

```
 TempData["UserID"] = user.ID;
```

In a different controller :

```
 var userID = TempData["UserID"];
```

**Using session :**

Configure session state in startup class :

In ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

In confugure:

```
 app.UseSession();
```

1. Define a string

   ```
   public const string SessionUserId = string.Empty();
   ```
2. We set a string

   ```
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionUserId)))
            HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionUserId , user.ID.ToString());
   ```
3. We can get defined string:

   ```
   var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionUserId);
   ```

More info in documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: But in .net core tempdata,viewbag and session not able to pass. Please share more Idea.

Comment: In this case you can use session. You have to add it in startup and then use set/get in the controllers. Make sure you set the session's expired time long enough.

Comment: How to set the session's expired time ?

Comment: services.AddSession(options =>
        {          
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15); 
        });

Comment: I add this. But don't know how to pass the value from one controller to another controller.

Comment: But it's not working for me..In Postman I need to pass without passing data in session.